# В чем отличие паттерна 'абстрактная фабрика' от паттерна 'строитель'?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Не понял в чем различия между паттернами 'абстрактная фабрика' и 'строитель'. На основе каких критериев выполняется выбор? Какие вопросы я должен задать себе, что бы понять какой порождающий паттерн из двух приведенных мне использовать?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33871/discussion-on-question-by-evgeniy-miroshnichenko-----).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Абстрактная фабрика** предоставляет интерфейс для создания семейств, связанных между собой, или независимых объектов, конкретные классы которых неизвестны.

**Строитель** отделяет конструирование сложного объекта от его представления, позволяя использовать один и тот же процесс конструирования для создания различных представлений

Основное различие между ними в том, что **строитель** делает акцент на пошаговом конструировании объекта, а **абстрактная фабрика** на создании семейств объектов. **Строитель** возвращает объект на последнем шаге, тогда как с точки зрения **абстрактной фабрики** продукт возвращается немедленно.

Comment: а примеры на C# можете привести?

Comment: Про строителя во втором абзаце вообще не понятно. Какие такие представления?

Comment: @Sergey представление - конечное состояние объекта. Отличный пример строителя - SqlBuilder, где методы select(), where() служат для конструирования, а представление - конечная строка sql

Comment: @vitidev Значит представление - это всего лишь объект, который получается в результате строительства?

Comment: @Sergey да. можно подменять строителей и получать разные результаты.

Comment: @vitidev На самом деле я знаю что такое буилдер, как мне кажется. Но я никак не могу понять вот этой фразы `отделяет конструирование сложного объекта от его представления`. Как? как можно отделить того, чего ещё нет? Ведь пока не построим, представления нет!

Comment: @Sergey вместо явного сложного создания объекта прямо в коде (акцент на внутреннем наполнении создаваемого объекта) вы создаете строителя, в котором прячется акцент на внутреннем наполнении объекта и акцентируетесь на  **управлении шагами** создания (детали шага спрятаны внутри строителя). В обоих случаях получите объект, но во втором случае код в котором описаны шаги создания не знает ничего о внутреннем представлении объекта (несогласованное состояние в процессе сборки)

Comment: _"объектов, конкретные классы которых неизвестны"_ -- т.е. в коде это выглядит так: `class AbstractFactory { public object GetItem() { ... }}` -- вызов GetItem возвращает объект, класс/тип которого неизвестен. И часто такое нужно?

Comment: @Stack, вы привели _слишком_ обобщенный случай, обычно в качестве выходного  используется базовый класс или интерфейс, но конструируется объект конкретных типов наследников

Answer (score -2):

Если на конкретных примерах, паттерн **Строитель** -

> SqlConnectionStringBuilder

В них вы задаете параметры, хост, порт, авторизация, логин, пароль, потом вызываете метод

> ToString()

И получаете конечный результат.
С **фабриками** не так. Для инициализации вы вызываете не конструктор, а специальный фабричный метод абстрактного класса или родителя, который возвращает экземпляр нужного потомка. Например:

`WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080");`

вернет HttpWebRequest, а если вы вызовете с другим значением аргумента:

`WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://localhost:21");`

вернет FtpWebRequest.

Comment: Ну и где в случае WebRequest вы увидели [абстрактную фабрику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))?